# getting error : GET https://script.google.co...t::ERR_ABORTED 404. how to do to correct it?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I tried to launch my test procedure to retrieve a returned image pub.
If , I have in my computer, it works well to retrieve a returned and shared image from google drive .

If, I used an other computer ans an other adress mail test, it failed . messag error :
" GET https://script.google.com/a/radiopresence.com/macros/s/AKfycbzxzpByUKkJFaDTIy01zvzblF3TUKWQOwBvy1sblMzTy_KHGis/exec?&callback=ctrlq_P&action=&callback=jQuery350010880660109206097_1645118368591&_=1645118368592 net::ERR_ABORTED 404"

how to do to correct it ?

see screenshot error below
[image]

here is a my little procedure, below .

```js
<!-- pub  -->
    <table>
       <tr>
         <td>
                <span><br />   
   <div  onload="test_pub()"  >   
   <div id="affiche_pub">  
   <script>
 
 // à suspendre  pour l'instant . les travaux sur la finalisation à l'ecran sont en cours. et ensuite, on passe la pub .... 
 
  function test_pub()              
  {              
       console.log('lancement de la procedure pour aller chercher limage pub');         
         var i = 0;  
         changeimg();
     }              
                
    function changeimg(i)
      
    {      console.log('Debut  function changeimg - Scipt Ecran pour affichage Pub');
   
   // ce lien ci dessous est pour la procédure appelée "Recuperation_image_Pub_V1"  
   var script_url = "https://script.google.com/a/radiopresence.com/macros/s/AKfycbzxzpByUKkJFaDTIy01zvzblF3TUKWQOwBvy1sblMzTy_KHGis/exec"
   
   var dataparm = "";
   var url = script_url+"?&callback=ctrlq_P"+dataparm+"&action=";
  // }
   
   console.log('Scipt Ecran pour affichage Pub : url pour aller chercher l image pub :'+url);

      var request =  jQuery.ajax({
      crossDomain: true,
      url: url ,
      method: "GET",
     dataType: "jsonp"
    });

  console.log('Scipt Ecran pour affichage Pub - request  :'+request ); 
  
  var result = request.Pub;
  console.log('Scipt Ecran pour affichage Pub - result  :'+result ); 
  
//   var REP_pub_image  ="O";
//   console.log('Scipt Ecran pour affichage Pub :===> Reponse sur la pub image (existe ou non ?)  :' +REP_pub_image   );
 
  //** publicitaire 
 var Pub_image = "";
   console.log('fin function function callimage ()');  
 // suspendu ci dessous pour le test du lancement pour récuperer l'image du retour si l'on utilise dans un autre ordinateur et // un autre adresse mail .  
 // } 
//    if ( i<4)
//      {i++; 
//      console.log('nb de lancement du  function changeimg :'+i);
//      }
//      else
//      {
//      i=0;
//      }
//       setTimeout("changeimg()", 10000);
       console.log('fin function changeimg - Scipt Ecran pour affichage Pub');
 }
  
  // chargement fenetre pub 
  window.onload = changeimg;
  
      // print the returned data
  function ctrlq_P(e) {
   console.log('debut function ctrlq_P - Form.html:');  
   console.log('function ctrlq_P - Form.html- parm  e: '+e);  
  
   var Pub_image = e.Pub;
   if (Pub_image.length > 0 )
  { console.log('function ctrlq_P - Form.html - URL Pub (Pub_image) : '+Pub_image );  
  
  var valeur_image_pub = document.getElementById('affiche_pub'); 
 
  var affiche_pub ='<img   align="left"  style="display:block;  width: 58%;"     src ="'+Pub_image+'"  alt=""  />'
 console.log('function data_screen2(res) -  affiche_pub  = '+affiche_pub);  
 
  valeur_image_pub.innerHTML = affiche_pub;
   }
   else
   {
   console.log('  function ctrlq_P - Form.html- Pub_image = null');  
   }
   
  console.log('fin  function ctrlq_P - Form.html');     
  }
  
   console.log('fin Scipt Ecran pour affichage Pub');
 

//  

        </script>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

in advance , thank you for your help .

Comment: Google is requiring a login - the file is not public.

Comment: An issue with the request. First try would be trying to check if you have the right permissions. You might need to login